# How do I log debug for a desktop app built with TideSDK?

Tags: debugging, logging, tidesdk

I'm involved in building an html5/js/css app that we want to package for both Mac and Win using TideSDK.  When using TideSDK Developer, I have access to all logging (Ti.API.debug, etc) in the console tab. Is there any way to see that same logging after I have deployed the packaged app to the desktop?

Thanks,
Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout the logging through webInspector console. The logs are also saved in the file system, check your application data directory for the log file.

Comment: Where is this data directory?